# Polymorphic Comments in both nested resource and simple resource ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have following relationship routes:

```
resources :courses, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :enrols, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :lectures, only: [:show]
end

resources :code_casts, :path => 'casts', :as => 'casts', only: [:index, :show]
resources :blogs, :path => 'blog', :as => 'blog', only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :blog_votes, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

I want polymorphic comments in courses, lectures, code_casts and blog.

Problem is lecture has a parent of course so route will be `course/course_id/lecture/id` and blog path will `blog/id` where comments will have different show pages.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? You can implement required logic (whose commets to show) in controller. `if params[:course_id] ...`, extract it into route and controller concerns.

Comment: In the rails cast provided in the link http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised. The comments are on the same resource levels. I do not know how I make nested resource association to the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, there is nothing special about deeply nested resources. So you might need something like this

```
# routes.rb
concern :commentable do
  resources :comments
end

resources :courses, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :enrols, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :lectures, only: [:show], concerns: [:commentable]
end

resources :code_casts, :path => 'casts', :as => 'casts', only: [:index, :show]
resources :blogs, :path => 'blog', :as => 'blog', only: [:index, :show], concerns: [:commentable] do
  resources :blog_votes, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

This will create nested `comments` resources for lectures and blogs.
Than you need to differentiate the path in a comments controller

```
# comments_controller
def create
  Comment.create(commentable: commentable, other_params...) # assuming you have `commentable` polymorphic belongs_to
end

# a little more ugly than Ryan suggests
def commentable
  if request.path.include?('blog') # be careful. any path with 'blog' in it will match
    Blog.find(params[:id]) 
  elsif params[:course_id] && request.path.include?('lecture')
    Course.find(params[:course_id).leactures.find(params[:id]) # assuming Course has_many lectures
  else
    fail 'unnable to determine commentable type'
  end
end
```

All 'magic' is in commentable method, where youare checking the path and determine which commentable object to pick. I use similar approach, but this exact code is written by memory without testing. Hopefully you've got the idea.